# ways to create a deadlock in servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

Could you please advise how we can create a deadlock in servlet, On way which I was thinking was one simple way to call doPost() method inside doGet() and doGet()method inside doPost() it will create deadlock situation for a servlet. Please advise are there any other ways.

Comment: Is this homework? What you describe won't create a deadlock, but an infinite loop which will eventually crash when you run out of stack space. See [Wikipedia antry for deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

Comment: Calling method A() inside method B(), and method B() inside method A() is not deadlock, but rather infinite loop (that will create StackOverflow exception). Deadlock is situation when few threads at the same time are waiting for each others activity to continue their task.

Comment: You may have got your post/get example [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/servlet-interview-questions-answers.html). I don't see how this is a deadlock. Maybe it means it will cause the servlet to appear to "lock up" and behave like it's "dead"... but that's not a deadlock in the technical sense of the word..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy servlet below and invoke it few times.

```
public class DeadLockServlet extends HttpServlet {
       private static long sleepMillis = 10000;
       private final Object lock1 = new Object();
       private final Object lock2 = new Object();

   private boolean switch = true;

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)  throws ServletException, IOException  {

        if(switch){
            switch=!switch;
            lock12();
        }
        else{
            switch=!switch;
            lock21();
        }
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("Done!");
        out.close();
  }

   private void lock12() {
       synchronized (lock1) {
           sleep();
           synchronized (lock2) {
               sleep();
           }
       }
   }

   private void lock21() {
       synchronized (lock2) {
           sleep();
           synchronized (lock1) {
               sleep();
           }
       }
   }

   private void sleep() {
       try {
           Thread.sleep(sleepMillis);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For every request web container creates one new thread.In my servlet I have kept 2 methods. One is doGet and another one is doPost.  Here my servlet code

```
public class DeadLockServlet extends HttpServlet {
       public static Object s = new Object();
       public static Object s1 = new Object();
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        synchronized (s) {
            System.out.println("Got lock of s in get");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(9977);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      System.out.println("waiting for lock of s1 in get");
        synchronized (s1) {
            System.out.println("Got lock of s1 in get");
        }
        }

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        synchronized (s1) {
            System.out.println("Got lock of s1 in post");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(9977);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     System.out.println("waiting for lock of s in post");
        synchronized (s) {
            System.out.println("Got lock of s in  post");
        }
    }}

}
```

My abc.jsp code here

```
  <form action="DeadLockServlet" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value='ok'/>
    </form>
```

I am sending request to my servlet from one browser http://localhost:8090/DeadLockTest/abc.jsp (for post method while clicking okbutton).

Another request from another browser like http://localhost:8090/DeadLockTest/DeadLockServlet (for Get method).
Now you will get the deadlock situation

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, (dare I say indefinite?), to create a deadlock. Your example is one in a way(Mostly just an infinite loop). The easiest way is to create a lock on an object that calls another method to get a lock on the same object in which case the lock will never release because it is waiting for the other method to acquire a lock, which it can't do because the object already has a lock on it.